# Weblogic 12.2.1 - Jdk 1.8 - Schema validation errors while parsing config.xml

Tags: java-8, weblogic12c, mojarra

I need to upgrade a weblogic server from 9.2 ( jdk 1.5) to 12.2.1 ( jdk 1.8).
For this, I upgraded in 3 steps:
- from 9.2 ( jdk 1.5) to 10.3.6 (jdk 1.6) OK
- from 10.3.6 (jdk 1.6) to 12.1.2 ( jdk 1.7) OK
- from 12.1.2 (jdk 1.7) to 12.2.1 ( jdk 1.8) NOK

For the last step, I compiled my project successfully with weblogic 12.2.1 and jdk 1.8 in Eclipse Mars 2.

But, when I want to run the server with this version, weblogic 12.2.1 Server administration console is running,
but I have a problem with deployments which have failed status.
I don't understand why deployment failed.

See the errors:

```
<Warning> <JMSExceptions> <BEA-045142> <WebLogic Server has detected a deprecated JMS Interop Module in your configuration. This feature will be removed in a future release. Oracle recommends that you take appropriate measures to remove dependencies on JMS Interop Modules.> 
 <Error> <Management> <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing /projectTCS/config/config.xml<40:3> - Expected elements 'jpa@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain deployment-configuration@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain wtc-server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain log@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain snmp-agent@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain snmp-agent-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain root-directory@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain console-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain java-service-console-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain console-context-path@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain console-extension-directory@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain server-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain coherence-server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain cluster@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain file-t3@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain messaging-bridge@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain production-mode-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain embedded-ldap@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain administration-port-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain administration-port@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain exalogic-optimizations-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain java-service-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain archive-configuration-count@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain config-backup-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain configuration-version@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain administration-m-bean-auditing-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain configuration-audit-type@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain cluster-constraints-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain app-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain library@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain domain-library@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ws-reliable-delivery-policy@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain machine@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-entity-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-registry@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain virtual-host@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain virtual-target@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain migratable-target@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ejb-container@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain web-app-container@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain cdi-container@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jmx@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain self-tuning@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain resource-management@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain path-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-bridge-destination@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain bridge-destination@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain shutdown-class@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain startup-class@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain singleton-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain mail-session@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jolt-connection-pool@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain log-filter@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain file-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain replicated-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jdbc-store@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-interop-module@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-system-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain custom-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain foreign-jndi-provider@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain admin-server-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain administration-protocol@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain wldf-system-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jdbc-system-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain saf-agent@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain error-handling@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain remote-saf-context@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain migratable-rmi-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain webservice-security@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-connection-consumer@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain auto-deploy-for-submodules-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain admin-console@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain internal-apps-deploy-on-demand-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain guardian-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ocm-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain msg-id-prefix-compatibility-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain log-format-compatibility-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain coherence-cluster-system-resource@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain restful-management-services@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain system-component@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain system-component-configuration@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain osgi-framework@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain webservice-testpage@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain server-migration-history-size@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain service-migration-history-size@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain coherence-management-cluster@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain partition@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain resource-group@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain resource-group-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain max-concurrent-new-threads@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain max-concurrent-long-running-requests@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain parallel-deploy-applications@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain parallel-deploy-application-modules@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-executor-service-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-scheduled-executor-service-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-thread-factory-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-executor-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-scheduled-executor-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain managed-thread-factory@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain partition-template@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain lifecycle-manager-end-point@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain interceptors@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain batch-config@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain debug-patches@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain partition-work-manager@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain diagnostic-context-compatibility-mode-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain batch-jobs-data-source-jndi-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain batch-jobs-executor-service-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain optional-feature-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain lifecycle-manager-config@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain site-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain enable-ee-compliant-classloading-for-embedded-adapters@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain' instead of 'security@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain' here in element domain@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.> 
<Error> <Management> <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing /projectTCS/config/config.xml<137:4> - Expected elements 'ws-reliable-delivery-policy@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain machine@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-entity-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-registry@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ... optional-feature-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain lifecycle-manager-config@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain site-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain enable-ee-compliant-classloading-for-embedded-adapters@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain' instead of 'file-realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain' here in element domain@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.> 
 <Error> <Management> <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing /projectTCS/config/config.xml<140:4> - Expected elements 'ws-reliable-delivery-policy@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain machine@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-entity-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-registry@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain virtual-host@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain virtual-target@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain migratable-target@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ejb-container@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain web-app-container@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain .... debug-patches@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain partition-work-manager@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain diagnostic-context-compatibility-mode-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain batch-jobs-data-source-jndi-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain batch-jobs-executor-service-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain optional-feature-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain lifecycle-manager-config@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain site-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain enable-ee-compliant-classloading-for-embedded-adapters@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain' instead of 'realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain' here in element domain@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.> 
<Error> <Management> <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing /projectTCS/config/config.xml<144:4> - Expected elements 'ws-reliable-delivery-policy@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain machine@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-entity-cache@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain xml-registry@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain jms-server@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain virtual-host@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain virtual-target@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain ... diagnostic-context-compatibility-mode-enabled@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain batch-jobs-data-source-jndi-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain batch-jobs-executor-service-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain optional-feature-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain lifecycle-manager-config@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain site-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain enable-ee-compliant-classloading-for-embedded-adapters@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain' instead of 'password-policy@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain' here in element domain@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.> 

<Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.>


 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationFactoryImpl@49c9f167 because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationFactoryImpl@799443f8 because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.RenderKitFactoryImpl@4f17f016 because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.RenderKitFactoryImpl@27b331b3 because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory@71cd6a4 because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactoryImpl@75076caa because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactoryImpl@757a6339 because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to inject org.ajax4jsf.application.DebugLifecycleFactory@43791829 because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Info> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <jsf.config.listener.version> <Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8-11 ( 20150717-1300 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8-11@14871) for context '/appl01'>


 <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?> 
 <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <BEA-000000> <Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.

at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
...
Caused By: javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl
at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:409)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:253)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:549)


...
Caused By: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at javax.faces.application.Application.subscribeToEvent(Application.java:1797)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)


<Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly..

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:725)
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I got below error and I fixed it by copying customized Jar files which is used in your project . Copy those files to C:\bea1034\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\mbeantypes and restart again . It worked for me .

This error comes because of missing jar files in weblogic config which is being refereed in config.xml file

Comment: Please edit your answer. It looks like you have a bunch of time stamp codes in your last sentence. Thanks!